# Salesforce Integration Where to Start

Tags: rest-api, soap-api

I started my career as a Salesforce Admin/ Developer(Pretty good at Apex/VF/Web development) and I don't have much knowledge on SOAP/REST integrations, I'm not even familiar with the terminology. Can anyone please guide me on where to start? Any sample integration guides would be helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can start with the [APEX Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/) which has some REST in it and will find plenty of other resources to pick and choose from that you can work with at the [SF Developer Documentaion Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs). Obviously, there's much you'll find in the [Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/) that applies to both REST and SOAP, but each has their own resource including [Force.com REST API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/) and [SOAP API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/) among others that are more specific to particular SF features like Live Agent, etc.